# Workflow task permissions removed in 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

From what I've gathered, in 2010 you could tell tasks to only be updatable by who they were assigned to. I can't find this setting in 2013 (specifically sharepoint online). I've read a few questions here that say you can only do it through code now. My client doesn't want any custom code, because they can't support it. Am I missing the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is removed from 2013 to support the new App Step.

More on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159(v=office.15).aspx)

Workaround to handle your requirement is to create workflow in 2010 and move it to 2013.

I found this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112631/setting-permissions-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow)